# How to tell whether a breaker panel can meet certain electrical requirements

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, gfci, 240v

I am a homebrewer and am planning on buying a fancy new piece of brewing equipment for my basement brewery. The electrical requirements of this equipment are as follows:

- 4 wire, 240V line for power
- Requires NEMA 14-30 outlet
- Requires 1 x 30 amp breaker
- Comes with a 5500W heating element
- Comes with 6 Foot power cord
- A GFCI breaker for added protection is recommended

Before I make this purchase I want to make sure my breaker panel can "handle it". I will of course have a professional electrician do the installs, but before I pay someone to come in and assess my panel, I figured it would be helpful to learn more about breaker panels and figure some of this stuff out on my own.

So I ask: **how can I tell whether my breaker panel can "handle" supplying voltage, amperage and wattage for all of these requirements?** What do I look for?

My panel:
[image]

Comment: A picture showing the panel with all the current breakers would help.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I added a picture; I was hesitant to do so at first because I really am hoping someone can explain _how_ you arrive at such decisions instead of just looking at my panel and giving me a "yes" or "no". But hopefully this helps.

Comment: First of all, you definitely cannot supply any new 240V loads with that panel as-is. 240V loads must be supplied by two-pole/two-space breakers, and you have only one space available right now. But since none of the existing breakers are GFCI/AFCI you might be able to consolidate a couple circuits into once space with tandem breakers (subject to load calculation). Second, that Square-D breaker (in spaces 5/7) doesn't belong in an Eaton panel. It should be replaced with a unit that is listed for the panel.

Comment: How many square feet is your house, how many watts is your range, and what's the Maximum Circuit Amps rating on your air conditioner? Also, can you get us better quality photos of your panel please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yeah it’s too blurry to make anything out

Comment: @nobody good eye, big problem.  OP could decommission some of those unused breaker spaces, but **inside that problem lies the solution**.  You have to swap it anyway... swap it for a quadplex breaker that will power both the A/C and the new homebrew system.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I don't think there are any unused breakers - all the installed breakers are labelled on the paper taped to the door, just not on the stickers next to the breakers. Yeah two are labelled "?" but they're probably hooked up to something - builders aren't known for spending money on breakers that aren't used.

Comment: Thanks everyone I will try to address you all in separate comments here. Hi @nobody (+1 for all comments above) -- **(1)** I'm thinking the best thing to do is test what every single current breaker goes to and see if I can consolidate and make room for a 240V-rated GFCI quad breaker, would you disagree? **(2)** Thanks for pointing out the Square-D breaker, I will check into it.

Comment: Thanks @ThreePhaseEel (+1): my house is approx 1700 sq ft. I'm happy to dig up the wattage and amperage ratings for my range/AC for you, but I have a few questions first if you don't mind: **(3)** if I were to somehow make room for a brand new quad breaker as others have suggested, would the specs for my range & AC no longer matter or factor into the equation (why or why not?!). And **(4)** just curious why you're asking about the wattage rating on the stove, and not the voltage and/or amperage, and why you're asking about the max amperage rating on the AC, and not the voltage and/or wattage!

Comment: Thanks @Harper-ReinstateMonica (+1) -- so it sounds like you are suggesting that the Square-D breaker feeding my AC needs to be replaced, and that I could replace it for a 240V GFCI breaker that could feed both my AC and homebrew system?

Comment: For what it's worth in case there are other details that might matter, this is a [Spike+ Solo all-in-one homebrew system](https://spikebrewing.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/35000176750-what-are-the-electrical-requirements-for-the-spike-solo-system-) I am considering purchasing.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup You could replace it with a quad breaker, yes, [something like this](https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/skuPage.BQ230230.html).  I'm not sure if skinny quadplex dual 2-pole 30A breakers are available **with GFCI**, though.  I've never seen such a beast, but I may be wrong.  If you want GFCI you may need to combine some of the singles into space savers to make room for a full size GFCI 2-pole breaker **and** also replace the A/C breaker separately.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup Yes.  You can replace your existing 2-pole 30A A/C breaker with a quad which fits in the same space but provides **two** double pole 30A breakers instead (ie: my link above).  Such a breaker does not provide GFCI protection, however, so if you are required by code to protect those circuits with GFCI then this is simply *not an option* and you'll need to first replace the A/C breaker with one which is suitable for your panel PLUS you will need to consolidate some other breakers into skinny space-savers to make space for the full-size 2-pole 30A breaker WITH GFCI that you need.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup The caveat is that there may exist somewhere a quadplex dual 2-pole 30A breaker out there **with** GFCI - maybe someone else has an answer to that but I don't think they exist.  As an aside, the link I posted above goes to the non common trip breaker - should have been [this](https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/skuPage.BQC230230.html) instead.  Need common trip on both of the 2-pole circuits.

Comment: What is the size of your main breaker?  It's out of focus but looks a bit like 100A.  With 100A service and an electric range, electric dryer, electric hot water, and A/C, I suspect service capacity is a bigger problem for you than physical space.  The  calculations discussed above will be more authoritative but unless your range, dryer, water heater and A/C are all bizzarely small I hope I'm reading your poorly focused photo incorrectly or you'll probably calculate that you need a service upgrade.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132265/discussion-on-question-by-hotmeatballsoup-how-to-tell-whether-a-breaker-panel-ca).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My bet is the added circuit wouldn't create an actual overload.

The first 4 requirements are kind of redundantly covered by the requirement for a [NEMA 14-30 outlet](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-30-Amp-Industrial-Flush-Mount-Shallow-Single-Outlet-Black-R10-00278-S00/300324233?MERCH=REC-_-searchViewed-_-NA-_-300324233-_-N), that is a 240v 4 wire 30A outlet, which is the proper size for 125% protection for 5500w/23A.

The Code method for determining calculated service capacity is a little involved adding watts per square foot, code required and actual additional dedicated circuits, determining motor/fan sizes and demand factors. There are samples [online](https://www.naperville.il.us/globalassets/media/forms/residential-load-calculation-worksheet-2017.xlsm).

This load calc is required at every new installation. Whether this calc would result with bad news could only be guess with info provided. It seems in my experience inspectors used to rarely require a new calc for a new single circuit, kind of like they presumed it was covered in the sq. ft. calculation. But it seems like nearly every new 14-30 now is a evse outlet, which certainly doesn't fit the sq. ft. narrative and many jurisdictions are requiring new load calcs with every 14-30 or larger circuit.

240v circuits require a wire from each of two adjacent 1" spaces. It has been suggested to use a [BQC quad breaker](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Eaton-BR-2-30-Amp-2-Pole-BQC-Common-Trip-Quad-Circuit-Breaker-BQC230230/100118580) that doubles up taking two wires from each of those spaces to feed two circuits. These can only be used in spaces designed and *Listed* to accept these special breakers. *Breakers that are allowed* will be listed on the panel cover label. It is likely new enough to be designed to accept these breakers due to the type of labels shipped with the panel, but that isn't proof. *The Square D breaker also won't be shown on the label as approved for this panel. If there was no GFCI recommendation or requirement then (assuming the AC breaker is 30A) buying one BQC230230 breaker, installing it in the space the alien Square D breaker is to serve both the AC and brewing equipment and you would be done. This method seems simple because it changes out one breaker that has to be changed anyway.*

[image]

*Next equipment recommendation/code requirement.* The GFCI recommendation is likely there to encourage you to check NEC requirements for the location you are installing the equipment. New in the 2020 NEC (which your jurisdiction may not have adopted yet) is a requirement for 240v circuits be GFCI protected in all the locations that 120v circuits previously required protection (like basements, sheds, and garages).

This brings us back to the quad recommendation.  GFCI protection to my knowledge is only available for 240v circuits at the [breaker](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Eaton-BR-30-Amp-2-Pole-Self-Test-Ground-Fault-Circuit-Breaker-GFTCB230CS/206677556), which requires two full dedicated beaker spaces *and we just put it on a shared space*, making the previously recommended replacement of the alien breaker with a quad not quite that easy. *But that is easily resolved, put the new GFCI breaker in the dryer location, land the brewing equipment there, and move the dryer wires to the location on the left where you installed the BQC breaker.*

Comment: Thanks so much @NoSparksPlease (+1) -- a few followup questions for you, if you don't mind! **(1)** When you say: _"which is the proper size for 125% protection for 5500w/23A"_, what is this 125% and where does 23A come from? Is this some sort of U.S. standard rating? **(2)** what is a "_14-30 circuit_" and what is an "_evse outlet_"? Thanks again!

Comment: 125% is the National Electrical Code required rating of wire nd breaker for many load types,(3+ hours, heating, motors). Watts are calculated as volts*amps, so 5500w/240=22.9A. EVSE is electric vehicle charging equipment. .

Comment: Re: 14-30. Receptacle configuration standards in the US were developed by the National  Electrical Manufacturers Association to insure that not only the correct voltage but the correct wire and breaker support the equipment being plugged in.. The first number (14) is a categorization of number of circuit conductors and voltage level, the second number is the amps http://www.attachmax.com/p/2018/11/nema-plug-chart-05fd4e5f6725d1d5d9b0130db099044d-email-letter-with-regard-to-nema-receptacle-chart.jpg

Comment: Thanks for those clarifications @NoSparksPlease. Do you think I could replace the Square D breaker with a quadplex/GFCI breaker and feed both my A/C and the homebrew system?

Comment: Physically it would work, but may not be code compliant if your local inspection authority has adopted the 2020 National Electrical Code changes that now require GFCI protection  240v receptacles. See language changes here -> https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/NEC-Content.php?sectionID=808.0

Comment: Thanks again @NoSparksPlease (+1), last question! Say my local inspection authority _has_ adopted these 2020 NEC changes...how would that change things for me? Another user has suggested combining some of the "singles" into "space savers" to make "room" for a 240V w/ GFCI. Would this be the correct (and NEC compliant) fix here? I assume that a non-GFCI 240v breaker is "skinnier" or "thinner" (takes up less "slots") than a GFCI 240v breaker? Thanks again!!

Comment: His "space saving" recommendation was a general idea, when he then implemented the idea he recommended the same BQC breaker that I did in the last paragraph of my answer. GFCI breakers require two full size spaces. Maybe my italicized edits clarify some.

Comment: To clarify a bit: Full size breakers come in plain, GFCI and AFCI versions. Half-size breakers are only available plain. The half-size (there are some panels that do it a little differently, but for practical reasons, this is the way it normally works) come in doubles (= 2 half-size in the space for a full size 120V breaker) or quads (= 4 half-size in the space for a full size 240V breaker). A quad can be 4 x 120V or 2 pairs - inner pair and outer pair = 2 x 240V.

Comment: Hi @NoSparksPlease (+1) I've spent some time doing my own learning and circled back to your answer on this from last week. One followup question if I may be so bold. It sounds like you are suggesting I take out the 240v Dryer breaker (located at spaces 1 and 3) and use it to replace the 240v Air Conditioner breaker (spaces 5 and 7)...

Comment: This gets rid of the Square D breaker (code violation). I could then put my brand new 240V, GFCI Brewery breaker back on spaces 1 and 3, and snip the wires going to the Dryer. Now I have my brewery setup on 1 and 3, and my A/C still on 5 and 7, but with a proper-rated breaker. **But where does my Dryer now go?** Or would the same breaker go to both the brewery and the dryer, and I would just need to know to _never_ run them both at the same time?

Comment: A BQC breaker fits two 2-pole (4 handles ) into the space that currently feeds a single 2-pole circuit. Product links were posted in a couple of comments, but I now added an image to the answer above. The outer two connected handles could feed the brewery and the inner set could feed the dryer. They operate independently, and are capable of delivering 30A each.

Comment: Ahhhhh, so the new BQC breaker feeds Dryer and A/C on spaces 1 and 3, and the GFCI breaker takes spaces 5 and 7, where the old Dryer 240v was?

Comment: Ahhh @NoSparksPlease I may have found a snag in this idea. The A/C is currently on a 20-amp 240v breaker. The BQC quad breaker (that would regulate both the A/C and the Dryer) is a 30-amp breaker. The Dryer requires 30-amp.

Comment: No problem, bqc220230 https://www.amazon.com/Eaton-BQC220230-Quad-Breaker-1-2P/dp/B004Q06GQ2/ref=sr_1_2?hvadid=77721895335059&hvbmt=be&hvdev=c&hvqmt=e&keywords=bqc220230&qid=1640139150&sr=8-2

Comment: If you you prefer to buy local BQC breakers probably won't be available at the big 2 home improvement box stores, but if you live near a big city you may have to call a couple wholesale distributors to see who carries Eaton products. Distributors are VERY brand specific.